# Use logic quantifiers to write...

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Use logical quantifiers to write:
"Everybody loves somebody sometimes" (Where U=all people)
I came up with this but not sure how to type symbols in here.

$$\forall x \in U\,: \exists y\in U: x \text{ loves } y.$$

So... upside down A="For all"
Backwards E for "there exists"
curly little e for "belongs to"
My apologies as I don't know how to insert symbols like those.  Am I on the right track to this?  Or is this not even close?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: `\forall` for $\forall$, `\exists` for $\exists$, `\in` for $\in$ (wrapped in dolar signs (`$`)). Check my edit to your post to see this, the `\,` are there to prove a better spacing (it acts just like a blank space).

Comment: What does "sometimes" mean?

Comment: I think the sentence is a bit ambiguous. For just "Everybody loves somebody", it can be translated $\forall x \exists y : xLy$ or $\exists x \forall y : yLx$. That is, it can be "each person loves someone else" or "there is someone loved by everyone". Also the "sometimes" adds to the ambiguity. I don't know if there is a 100% correct answer.

Comment: I'd just say that it means "there exists a point in time at which a person x loves some person y".

Comment: If we're being super finicky, we could use a relation $L(x, y, t)$ to mean "$x$ loves $y$ at time $t$". Then you'd just need to qualify $t$ a bit.

Comment: That would be $\forall x\, \exists t \,\exists y, L(x,y,t)$, right? Although, if the universe of discourse is the set of people, this doesn't work.

Comment: That still leaves at least 4 possible interpretations.  Such as "there is a time when there is a person that is loved by everyone" or "for every person A, for some other person B, for some time t, f(A, B, t)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct except the first : or 'such that' isn't needed.
$$
\forall\; x\in U\;\exists \;y\in U : x \text{ loves } y
$$
another way to write this is 
$x\in U\implies \;\exists y\in U: x$ loves $y$.

Comment: I'd say the other such that isn't needed either.

Comment: I can't read it in English otherwise....

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Yeah it is ambiguous the way that was phrased.  For the purposes of being introduced to this whole idea of symbolic logic, I figure we're being asked to keep this pretty simple.  However the creative answers involving time were pretty cool too.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall Body(1)\; \exists Body(2)\; \exists Time(t)\; (Body(1)\ne Body(2)\land Body(1)\; loves\; Body(2)\; at \;Time(t)).$

Answer (score 0):

With apologies to Dino, that sentence *is* a bit ambiguous. Here is one way to look at it:

$\forall x:[P(x) \implies \exists y: \exists t:[P(y) \land T(t) \land L(x,y,t)]]$

where

$P(x)$ means $x$ is a person

$T(t)$ means $t$ is an instant in time

$L(x,y,t)$ means $x$ loves $y$ at instant in time $t$